# Question about Partial Sun

Tags: landscaping, sunlight, hydrangea

I just planted  sister theresa hydrangea in my front lawn next to the entrance.  My front faces South.  Should I replant them  in my back yard because of the sun?

Answer (score 2):

Hydrangeas do best in partial or dappled shade in soil that does not regularly dry out - a south facing position, unless it is partially shaded by other shrubs, is not the best of growing conditions, so yes, it might be better to plant elsewhere instead.